# Possible to make discord tts not read out username with discord bot python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is it possible to make this not say "Bot said 5" because then it messes up the countdown as it all because out of sync?

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, "5", tts=True)
await asyncio.sleep(1) 
await client.send_message(message.channel, "4", tts=True)
await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Thanks

Comment: You could try doing
`await client.send_message(message.channel, "5\n4", tts=True)` which sends '5' and then '4' one second later

Comment: As far as I know, the `discord.py` bot just sets a `tts` flag on the message it sends to discord.  The discord client that the user is using is what actually generates the speech message.  I don't think you can control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of TTS messages is entirely on the Discord client. `discord.py` cannot control how the message is read out by the client to users. Instead, it merely sets a flag on the message to signal that it should be a TTS message (see: [Discord API docs.](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)) There is no library that can change how a TTS message is because Discord's underlying API does not support it.

Per Mehvix's [comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230891/possible-to-make-discord-tts-not-read-out-username-with-discord-bot-python#comment91411593_52230891) you could send a single message with each number on a new line to count down and only read the bot's name once, e.g.

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, "3\n2\n\1\nTime's up!", tts=True)
```